# Trying to setup keycloak with mySQL but fails due to timezone issue

Tags: mysql, docker, keycloak

So, we're trying to setup keycloak using the `quay.io` docker image and connecting it with our mySQL database. While startup, we see this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: 
The server time zone value 'CDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. 
You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration
 property) to use a more specific time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

We can't reset our mysql or mysql host instance timezone - is there any other way we can override the `serverTimezone` parameter?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can set timezone. If `quay.io` based on debian. You can try something similar to

```
ENV TZ=Asia/Colombo
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

Please change timezone to same as your MySQL instance.

To build `Quay` image, please follow official [guide](https://docs.quay.io/guides/building.html)

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest 
USER root 
ENV TZ=UTC 
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

You no need to `sudo` as you use `root` user

Comment: are these commands supposed to be specified in a Dockerfile?

Comment: We're not using a Dockerfile to build a docker image :( We're directly pulling it from `quay.io`'s repository

Comment: @Saturnian Yes, in the `Dockerfile` .You can create your own `quay.io` image with timezone set. I think its the best way

Comment: @Saturnian Please try updated answer with Dockerfile

Comment: I tried this, I set the timezone to `CDT` (same as the `mysql` instance) however the error still persists. Tried it with `UTC` and still fails :/ Any other ideas?

Comment: Not proud of this but this is what I've been trying now: `docker run -p 8080:8080 --name keycloak -e KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG -e KEYCLOAK_USER=kc-admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -e DB_ADDR="mysql.hostname.com" -e DB_PORT="3306/keycloak?serverTimezone=UTC" -e DB_VENDOR=MYSQL -e DB_DATABASE= -e DB_USER=keycloak -e DB_PASSWORD=p@ssw0rD  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak` but this fails too because somewhere a `/` is added and '`UTC/`' timezone is not recognized by jdbc

Comment: NOT proud of what I've done but I got this working by purely manipulating the Docker arguments for DB. It'll do for now :)